# Коллекции Java (ArrayList)

Tags: java, arraylist, коллекции

Хотел сделать задание связанное с коллекциями Java. Решил воспользоваться ArrayList.
Но столкнулся с рядом проблем:

при добавлении в коллекцию пишет

> cannot find symbol method ToyBlocks

А при попытке сравнить объекты через компаратор ругается на ошибку:

> int cannot be deferenced

Подскажите, в чем ошибки и как исправить?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

class ToyBlocks {
    String name;
    int amount;
    int uah;
    int kopeck;
    ToyBlocks(String name, int amount,int uah, int kopeck) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.uah = uah;
        this.kopeck = kopeck;
    }
}

class ToyBlocksComparator implements Comparator {

@Override
public int compare(Object toyblocks1, Object toyblocks2) {
        return ((ToyBlocks) toyblocks1).uah.compareTo(((ToyBlocks) toyblocks2).uah);//int cannot be deferenced
    }
}

public class SortBlocks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ToyBlocks> blocks = new ArrayList(6); 
        blocks.add(ToyBlocks("первый набор", 18, 18, 0));// cannot find symbol method ToyBlocks
        blocks.add(ToyBlocks("Второй набор", 12, 12, 0));
        blocks.trimToSize();
        Collections.sort(blocks, new ToyBlocksComparator());
    }

}
```

Comment: я их написал в вопросе

Comment: У вас не хватает `new`  Надо `blocks.add(new ToyBlocks......`  и все таки писать лист надо бы `ArrayList<ToyBlocks> blocks = new ArrayList<ToyBlocks>(6);` либо `ArrayList<ToyBlocks> blocks = new ArrayList<>(6);` в 7+ версии

Comment: А что делать  с int cannot be deferenced? Я та кпонимаю проблема связана с типами? Но хотел узнать конкретнее

Comment: Потому, что вы вызываете метод `compareTo` у примитивного типа `int` , которое содержится в `toyblocks1.uah` ...а он (метод compareTo) может быть вызван только у референсных типов... у объектов, крч))...... как следствие, вам нужно организовать `return` простым способом, т.е. вернуть -1, 0 или 1, сравнив числа на больше меньше... либо использовать `return Integer.compare(одно число, второе число)`

Comment: Кстати, почему вы в `compare` используете `Object `, а не `ToyBlocks` в качестве типа входного параметра?

Comment: сам не знаю на автомате переписал. Просто эту тему самому надо рассмотреть вот и делаю по примеру

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Вы имели  в вилу вот так:class ToyBlocksComparator implements Comparator {

public int compare(ToyBlocks toyblocks) {
        ToyBlocks tmp = (ToyBlocks)toyblocks;
        if(this.uah < toyblocks.uah) {return -1;}   
        else if(this.uah > toyblocks.uah){return 1;}
        return 0;  
}
}

Comment: что-то типа того... только не стоит менять вопрос уже в процессе.......откатите его на тот, что был.... с тем кодом.. и желательно все вопросы продублировать не в виде комментов, а ниже/выше кода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Так как лист ожидает, что будут добавлены объекты типа `ToyBlocks`, то при вызове метода `add` у листа нужно писать `blocks.add(new ToyBlocks......`, т.е. добавлять ключевое слово `new` перед `ToyBlocks`, что позволяет создать объект данного типа и поместить его в коллекцию.

   Простой вызов `ToyBlocks(.....)` означает просто вызов метода `ToyBlocks`. А так как это метода нет в классе, то выходит ошибочка `cannot find symbol method ToyBlocks`. Собственно о чем там и говорится: *Не могу найти метод такой-то*
2. Объявлять коллекцию все же стоит с использованием дженериков, т.е. вместо

   ```
    ArrayList<ToyBlocks> blocks = new ArrayList(6);
   ```

   писать

   ```
   ArrayList<ToyBlocks> blocks = new ArrayList<ToyBlocks>(6);
   ```

   для *Java 7+*

   ```
   ArrayList<ToyBlocks> blocks = new ArrayList<>(6);
   ```
3. Ошибка

   > int cannot be deferenced

   в методе `compare()` возникает потому, что вы вызываете метод `compareTo` у примитивного типа `int` , которое содержится в `toyblocks1.uah`, а он (метод compareTo) может быть вызван только у референсных типов...у объектов, крч))

   Если бы вы передавали или сравнивали не `int`, а `Integer`, тогда бы могло и сработать.

   Но...как следствие, вам нужно организовать `return` простым способом, т.е. вернуть -1, 0 или 1, сравнив числа на больше меньше.
   Например:

   ```
   public class ToyBlocksComparator implements Comparator<ToyBlocks> {
       @Override
       public int compare(ToyBlocks t1, ToyBlocks t2){
           return t1.uah - t1.uah; // Ninja method :-) 
       }
   }
   ```

   Можно и длинным путем: `if (t1.uah < t1.uah) return -1; if (t1.uah == t1.uah) return 0; if (t1.uah > t1.uah) return 1;`

   либо использовать обертку `Integer` и вызвать `compare` уже на нем.

   ```
   return Integer.compare(одно число, второе число);
   ```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40453/discussion-on-answer-by----java-arraylist).